# Getting unexpected results using selenium waitForNotVisible

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have some selenium based tests a feature where an item is deselected on the page, which causes that element to be removed from the page.  Because it is ajax based I do a click for the deselect action, and then wait for the element to no longer be on the page before moving on.  the basic flow is

```
    click(TargetElement)
    if(isElementPresent(targetElement)){
        waitForNotVisible(targetElement)
    }
    ...
```

This seems to work 100% of the time when run against a local selenium server instance, but when run against the selenium grid I have set up, it always times out on waitforNotVisible (in both cases, the conditional is always met).

Originally when this was failing, I didn't have the conditional and I thought that would clear it up, but it didn't.  Maybe my expectations for waitForNotVisible are not correct, but I wonder why this would be working locally and not against the grid.  All of my other tests seem to work fine via both methods.

And yes, I am using selenium 1; at the moment moving to selenium2/Webdriver is not an option in the short term, so please don't suggest using webdriver as a solution.  At the moment I'm most interested in understanding why this would fail as-is.

Comment: In the RC terminal, look for the result of execution of the command within waitForNotVisible. What exception is it throwing?

Comment: I'll have to go back and check the actual exception thrown but the message I remember was a timeout during the wait.